# Postgres удаление из одной таблицы, используя условие из другой таблицы

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть две таблицы. Таблица шапка `header` и таблица для хранения `data`

Как мне удалить данные из таблицы `data` не удаляя записей из `header`

```
delete from data
       where data.header_id = header.id and header.type = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
delete from data d
using header h
where h.id = d.header_id and h.type = 1
```

[Sql Fiddle пример.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bd389/1)

Comment: а чем мой вариант плох кст? тоже ведь решение?

Comment: Да ничем не хуже, в принципе. Просто другой вариант решения одной и той же задачи, более многословный только разве только что. Я хотел его тоже написать, но Вы успели раньше.

Comment: @des1roer, этот вариант просто красивее

Answer (score 1):

```
delete from data
   where id in (select data.id
                       from  data, header where       
               data.header_id = header.id and header.type = 1)
```